# not able to mute someone in discord.js - node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to mute someone manually in discord.js
by adding:

```js
if(message.author == /*muted list*/){
message.delete();
return;
}
```

and I need to extract the list from a json file (and I did)

```json
{
  "muted":[
    //someone's ID,
    //someone else's ID
    ]
}
```

I got the the IDs in a variable.
and logged it into console to see if I did it correct
console output:

```json
[  some id , some else id ]
```

so I put the variable in the `/*muted list*/`  in the js file.
but it did nothing.
help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got JSON converted into list you can simply check string from the list with `.includes()`

```js
if (yourlist.includes(message.author.id)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
if (<muted.json>.find(x => x.id == message.author.id)) {
    message.delete();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.